# How to add a scroll-to-top floating button in volusion site?

Tags: javascript, css, html, scrolltop, volusion

I have a volusion site. I want to add a scroll-to-top floating. I tried lot of js or css code but it doesn't work. Any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should post the things you tried and that didn't work, so we can help you fix what you already have.

Comment: Hi Arian, I follow the exact step of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
<style type="text/css">
.scrollToTop {position:fixed;bottom:100px;right:100px;}
</style>

<a class="scrollToTop" href="javascript:scrollToTop();">Scroll to top</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollToTop() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0); // If you work with jQuery,
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // Or not.
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it doesnt work. I pasted the code inside <head> </head>.

Comment: Try paste the code inside <body> section. Do you work with jQuery?

Comment: Its working. Thanks. How do I make it float on the right bottom? Yes, I am working on jQuery site.